# Find the next number in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

I am giving this question to see how much time people take to solve such problems and to know how the idea struck their minds . I solved but it took a lot of time(12 minutes) for the solution to strike my mind .I want to check how much time generally people take for these questions .

Find the next number in the sequence

$83 , 121 , 16 , 49 , 169 ,256 , ......$

> **Answerers please also share how much time it took  to solve this problem** and also the possible ways you tried to finally arrive at
>   the answer . Maths is fun , sequence is more fun

..

Comment: $169 = (2+5+6)^2$

Comment: It is a sequence not a series.

Comment: That 83 looks somewhat odd :-/

Comment: No. starting can be anything. It is the base for the sequence

Comment: The sequence continues $$83,121,16,49,169,256,169,256,\ldots$$

Comment: @Kaster Then try $82, 100,1,\ldots$ or $84,144,81,\ldots$. Hm, could it be that $83$ is the most interesting possible two-digit starting value?

Comment: Beautiful @DanielFischer . How much time did it take for you ? How did you figure out so quickly .

Comment: $83 , 121 , 16 , 49 , 169 ,256, \dots= 83, (11)^2, 4^2, 7^2, (13)^2, (16)^2,\dots.$

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam Don't know how long it took. Not very long, the squares were kind of a giveaway - although I was tempted to answer $42$.

Comment: @DanielFischer , I feel like falling to your feet . Amazing you are .

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam No. Just sometimes one sees things easily, other times not. When one doesn't see it, nobody notices, of course.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer , what about our answer 169 and answer got by Lord Soth using lagrange interpolation . what is to be infered from these 2 answers ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why not 29 as the most interesting starting value?

Comment: Sorry, but sequences which rule depends on its representation (eg,  only make sense in decimal representation) are kinda second-class sequences to me.

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam You can continue any finite start of a sequence in any way you like, you can always find a rule for the chosen continuation. In this case, the kind of the question suggested a different simple rule than the Lagrange interpolation polynomial, so I arbitrarily [not really, it was what I expected to be the expected answer] chose that.

Comment: Then these sequence based questions are asked in exams , are they asked even though there is no unique answer . Is that fair ?

Comment: I have the nagging suspicion that the posers of these questions don't know that.

Comment: There are chances that each student will come up with a different answer right ?

Comment: Not only this question , as you say any sequence can be extended in any way we want , means that there are many answers for the same question . Important thing is these sort of questions are asked in competitive exams .

Comment: Clearly the sequence continues $0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...$

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam "Then these sequence based questions are asked in exams, are they asked even though there is no unique answer" Yes. "Is that fair?" No, to the point that one wonders why students failing such so-called exams do not sue the authors.

Comment: "I am giving this question to see how much time people take to solve such problems" — that's something you cannot infer from the answers; you don't know when the first one to answer has seen the question. And for any but the first answer the time may have been influenced by the availability of the first answer, so you certainly won't get anything even close to a reasonable statistics (not that you'd get that anyway from the number of answers to be expected to a single SE question). Not to mention that the first one to solve it may decide not to post the solution.

Answer (score 10):

It is trivial not to observe that the sequence is the polynomial
$$(263 x^5)/120-(1121 x^4)/24+(8915 x^3)/24-(31915 x^2)/24+(41197 x)/20-974$$
evaluated at $1,2,3,4,5,6$. Substituting $x=7$, we obtain $384$ as the next element.

Comment: Clearly, this is the only correct answer! ;)

Comment: How did you arrive at this polynomial ?

Comment: Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: @Harish: given any two sets of $n$ numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, there is a unique polynomial $p$ with $p(x_j)=y_j$, $j=1,\ldots,n$. Google "Lagrange polynomial".

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial

Comment: Ya thanks just now did this in wolfram alpha after being directed to lagrange interpolation by @njguliyev .

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam, in case you're confused, this answer is a joke; the purpose is to show that there are infinitely many sequences you can make which fit your initial terms. For example, I could make my sequence exactly like yours for the first 6 terms, and then suddenly switch to $-34102495073$ as the next number.

Comment: Oh , this was a slap on my face for having thought that the sequence has a unique answer. Ha Ha Ha . But really interesting . I came to know of lagrange interpolation .Really awesome .

Comment: @George: it was clear to me that it was a joke, but I'm still surprised that the polynomial seems to take integer values on all positive integers.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You all think this is a joke isn't it? Hahaha... That polynomial has the answer to all the questions in this universe.

Comment: Jokes aside, these questions would be a lot more fun if there was a "Turing machine size constraint" for the calculation of the next element. Then, fun-spoilers like me wouldn't exist.

Comment: But your answer made me learn a new thing .How come they ask such ambiguous questions in exam ... hmm funny ..

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam It is great to see that this answer served a purpose then :)

Comment: @MartinArgerami If one continues a finite sequence of integers via polynomial interpolation (of minimal degree), the sequence will continue to consist of integers. You can see this by noting that the same continuation is obtained by working with repeated differences.

Answer (score 4):

There is no unique solution to such a problem. For any arbitrary choice of $t$ the sequence
$$a_n := 720t-974+(\tfrac{41197}{20}-1764t)n+(1624t-\tfrac{31915}{24})n^2+(\tfrac{8915}{24}-735t)n^3+\cdots$$
$$\cdots + (175t-\tfrac{1121}{24})n^4+(\tfrac{263}{120}-21t)n^5+tn^6$$
satisfies $a_1=83,$ $a_2=121,$ $a_3=16,$ $a_4=49,$ $a_5=169,$ and $a_6=256$.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems that the "correct" answer was quickly found by many commentators, often within very few minutes, but has not been posted yet, here goes:

> For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $Q(n)$ denote the digit sum of $n$, that is $$ Q(n)=\begin{cases}n&\text{if }0\le n\le 9\\r+Q(q)&\text{if }n=10k+r\text{ with }k\ge1,0\le r\le 9\end{cases}$$. Then the sequence obeys the recursion $a_{n+1}=Q(a_n)^2$. Hence the seuence continues $169,256,169,256,\ldots$

The exact behaviour depends on the starting value $a_1$, but the sequence is bounded from above: For $a_n<10^{k+1}$ we have $a_{n+1}\le 81k^2<10^k$ as soon as $k\ge3$, hence the sequence is decreasing until it falls and stays below $1000$. Therefore the sequence must be eventually periodic. The given sequence is presented just immediately before the first repetition. The only periods of length one are $1$ and $81$. The only period of length two is seen in the problem statement: $169,256$. By inspection of all starting values $\le 999$, there are no longer periods. Also, there is no starting value below $1000$ with a longer pre-period than $83$ (though there are many with equal length).